# Family member got offended when my uncle gave her a compliment which she thinks is not ok to give to a young woman

Tags: conversations, family, gender

So we have a groupchat on messenger which includes all family members (20 persons) now 1 girl posted a picture of a magazine in which her picture is.

A lot of aunts said: "wow you look great!" etc.
And 1 uncle responded "are you in [Dutch magazine name]? :D"

This was my uncle way of saying in a joking way that she looks awesome.
The dutch magazine always has covers of girls, sometimes in swimsuits or dressed a bit seductivaly but NEVER nude or topless.

The girl reacted back "this is very inappropriate, as a young woman I don't want reactions like this. I want that people appreciate me for who I am and not for my looks! If I was a boy I wouldn't receive such reactions."

The thing is in the groupchat we laugh with every family member, fat, old, small, black or white. Its just our family humour.

3 uncles and a nephew left the conversation because they don't want to watch every word they say and think that she overreacted.

How to deal with situations like this?

Comment: Hi Thomas, welcome to IPS. Can you please clarify? What do you want to convey? To who? What's the idea (the person and the IP skill involved) behind this story? As it stands, your text will mostly attract VTC and DV, but if you have a clear idea of what you want to achieve (and make it on-tpic for this stack), then we will certainly be able to help you rephrase (if needed) and answer. Thanks.

Comment: for example, do you want to persuade your cousin the comment was fine? explain to your uncle why it was not fine? get the people who left the chat to come back? what is your goal?

Comment: What is the country involved? The level of sexism tolerated in one society would be way too much for another.

Comment: @carduus : Dutch / The Netherlands ?

Comment: It may or may not matter for this specific situation, but why was the picture in the magazine? Was it a candid shot she happened to be in and was printed? Did she go out for a photo shoot as a model?

Comment: I didn't really see the actual problem, perhaps she overreacted. The "for who I am" passage is inappropriate to me. People who post pictures always and everywhere nowadays only show their look, how can they expect comments about attitude and personality? Praise for being a good person is not simply achieved by pictures all over. Less than ever if one appears in a magazine. Of course still it is a matter of how a comment is given - we can't evaluate uncle's comment properly. First thing you should do is bring the discussion down to a normal level.

Comment: @Upper_Case - It seems clear to me from the question that there was no actual picture in any magazine, the uncle was only referencing it as an indirect way of saying "you look good enough to be a model" or "...to appear in [the magazine]".

Comment: The first sentence says: "now 1 girl posted a picture of **a magazine in which her picture is**." That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: After reading it twice it seems to me that there were two magazines. First one had the picture of the girl, second one the uncle referenced was male-pleasure oriented. Could you edit your question so it is clear what is the topic/focus of first magazine? If I posted picture of myself standing in garden in "Gardening" magazine such comments would make me sad. If the magazine was "Young scientist" it would make me furious.